# Delete all rows in sharepoint list using Client Context and CAML Query

Tags: c#-4.0, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-list, sharepoint-clientobject

I am new to SharePoint and want to delete all rows in a SharePoint list using C# **ClientContext** class and **CAML Query**.

How can i achieve it efficiently?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I solved it. The learning was that we need to delete the items of list in reverse order.

**Link**: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitemcollection.delete.aspx

```
ListItemCollection listItems = oList.GetItems(CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery());
clientContext.Load(listItems,
                    eachItem => eachItem.Include(
                    item => item,
                    item => item["ID"]));
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

var totalListItems = listItems.Count;
Console.WriteLine("Deletion in " + currentListName + "list:");
if (totalListItems > 0)
{
    for (var counter = totalListItems - 1; counter > -1; counter--)
    {
        listItems[counter].DeleteObject();
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
        Console.WriteLine("Row: " + counter + " Item Deleted");
    }
}
```

Comment: As far as efficiency goes you would probably be well served to move the ExecuteQuery() statement outside of the loop.

Comment: If you move the ExecuteQuery to the outside of the loop, and you have many deletes sent as 'one execution' you could potentially run into an exception where Sharepoint thinks your request is too big (it happened to me with a couple thousand deletes). See http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/44894/client-object-model-microsoft-sharepoint-client-serverexception-the-request

Comment: i Agree with @n00b but in order to reduce network overhead I'd add `if (counter % 100 == 0){ clientContext.ExecuteQuery(); }`

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround:
- Create a items (said: deleteAllItems), on a new list (said: configuration).

- Use CAML to change that deleteAllItems value from False to True.
- then, use workflow,

  if deleteAllItems == True, delete all items.

  reset deleteAllItems to False.

Solve the client side performance issue. :)